# How can i switch to slave database in case of master crash?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, replication

I have 2 MySQL instances. One is master and the second is a slave. I want to configure the rails app in a way that if the connection to my master database failed, then auto-connect to the slave database and slave will become master. In this way, the site will never go offline due to the MySQL server crash.
But I am not able to find any solution in rails with mysql2 adapter to do so. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Your server(s) are supposed to recognise this situation and reconfig the slave to be the master. Dont try and do it in your rails code

Comment: Thank you. But we need to move Applications to Use New Master, which means change configuration of connection to a new master. Because it gives error connecting to MySQL as the server is down. Without app config change how the system will point to a new master?

Comment: NO! The automation software should see the crash and start the failover process, reconfiguring the Slave system to become the Master, change ip addresses etc etc. This is not the job of an application